# Laravel: Allow soft deleted models in a hasManyThrough relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a has many through relationship like this:

```
class Venue {
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Order::class, Offer::class);
    }
}
```

However the `Offer` model can be soft deleted: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#soft-deleting

This means the function, will not return any orders that have a soft deleted offer.

How can I allow the function to return orders that have soft deleted offers.

Note that I am using Laravel 5.1 (although solutions in newer versions is appreciated).

Answer (score 1):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#querying-soft-deleted-models

You can use the `->withTrashed()` method on the relationship.

Comment: But does this include with trashed for offers or orders

Comment: I don't have Laravel available to me right now, but I think you can get it to work by adding the ->withTrashed() method behind the hasManyThrough() method. If this doesn't work, I recommend you to add the withTrashed() method behind the relation to Offer from the Order class. One of these should fix your problem.

Comment: `$this->withTrashed()->hasManyThrough(Order::class, Offer::class)` gives `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::hasManyThrough()` error

Comment: You should turn it around, like this: `$this->hasManyThrough(Order::class, Offer::class)->withTrashed()`

Comment: That gives me: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::withTrashed()`

Comment: Do you use the SoftDeletingTrait, if not, you should add this line in the top of your Model Class `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;`

Comment: Unfortunately, the `withTrashed` refers to the Order models in this case, and not the Offer class, which is the inversion of what OP wants. We need a method to return only non-deleted Orders from all Offers (even deleted).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like follow :

```
$venue->orders()->withTrashedParents()->withTrashed();
```